# i drew lots of anime in my sketch book what should i do?

Tags: drawing

im kinda scared like i draw anime a lot and the Prophet (saw) said according to the saheeh hadeeth: “Every image maker will be in the Fire.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers, those who tried to imitate the creation of Allaah.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The makers of these images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and they will be told, ‘Give life to that which you have created.’”  what should i do to get forgiven for this,what should i do with all my drawings?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. "What should I do"-Questions hardly fit in our model I recommend you to re-phrase your question to make it more focused and better answerable.

Answer (score -1):

[Anas narrated that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:](https://sunnah.com/urn/678050)

> Every son of Adam sins, and the best of the sinners are the repentant.

Whatever happen happen now best is to repaint and Allah will forgive!